# How to transfer data from fragment to fragment through Bundle

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

Below is the adapter code of first fragment , here and sending data to second fragment StoreDetails.

```
holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    StoreDetails fragment = new StoreDetails();

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("store_id",pojo.getSTORE_ID());
                    bundle.putString("store_name",pojo.getSTORE_NAME());
                    bundle.putString("address",pojo.getSTORE_ADDRESS());
                   // bundle.putString("status",pojo.getSTATUS());
                   // bundle.putString("teammember",pojo.getSTATUS());

                   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                   FragmentManager manager=fragment.getFragmentManager();
    // in below line I am getting error 

                    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment,"fragment");
                    ft.addToBackStack("fragment");
                    ft.commit();

                }
            });
```

Below is the StoreDetails fragment

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();

            mstore_id = bundle.getString("store_id");
            mstore_name =bundle.getString("store_name");
            mstoreaddress= bundle.getString("address");
            mstorestatus = bundle.getString("status");
            mteammember = bundle.getString("teammember");
```

The error I'm receiving is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.app.FragmentTransaction
>   android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object
>   reference at Adapter.Tab1_Adapter$1.onClick(Tab1_Adapter.java:78)

Comment: what kind of problem you faced now

Comment: share your log cat report?

Comment: Wait am sending log

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at Adapter.Tab1_Adapter$1.onClick(Tab1_Adapter.java:78)

Comment: use `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` or `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: issue solved ...

Answer (score 2):

FragmentManager will be `null` until it is attached to the activity.

instead of using

```
FragmentManager manager=fragment.getFragmentManager();
```

use

```
 getActivity().getFragmentManager() or getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```